# Trying to connect our driver to a connection pool

Tags: java, database, spring, connection, connection-pooling

Basically my problem is I am trying to incorporate a connection pool into my application. In my database connection class we have set all of the different properties for the pool properties.

```
public static Connection getConnection() {

    try { 

        PoolProperties poolProperties = new PoolProperties();



        String url = prop.getUrl();
        String drivername = prop.getDriverClassName();
        String username = prop.getUsername();
        String password = prop.getPassword();
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);




        poolProperties.setUrl(url);
        poolProperties.setDriverClassName(drivername);
        poolProperties.setUsername(username);
        poolProperties.setPassword(password);

        poolProperties.setMaxActive(MAX_ACTIVE);
        poolProperties.setMaxIdle(MAX_IDLE);
        poolProperties.setMinIdle(MIN_IDLE);
        poolProperties.setInitialSize(MIN_POOL_SIZE);
        poolProperties.setMaxWait(MAX_WAIT);
        poolProperties.setRemoveAbandonedTimeout(REMOVE_ABANDONED_TIMEOUT);
        poolProperties.setMinEvictableIdleTimeMillis(MIN_EVICTABLE_IDLE_TIMEMILLIS);
        poolProperties.setValidationQuery(Validation_Query);
        poolProperties.setValidationInterval(VALIDATION_INTERVAL);
        poolProperties.setTimeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis(TIME_BETWEEN_EVICTION_RUNS_MILLTS);
        DataSource datasource = new org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource();

         ((org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource) datasource).setPoolProperties(poolProperties);
          datasource.createPool();



         logger.info("The connection is from" + prop.getDriverClassName());
```

When we run it on our SOAP UI Its still giving me back the information from our database that we want. However I'm still getting an error the console as follows

```
java.sql.SQLException: com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:254)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:182)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:702)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:634)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init(ConnectionPool.java:488)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.<init>(ConnectionPool.java:144)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.pCreatePool(DataSourceProxy.java:116)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.createPool(DataSourceProxy.java:103)
```

I'm not quite sure what the problem is exactly. I think the connection pool is not successfully connecting with the driver

Comment: Is your application running within tomcat?

Answer (score 0):

I see you are using tomcat since you are using tomcat jdbc pool config.

> The JDBC driver has to be visible to the same classloader as the data
>   source factory itself. The data source factory library is placed in
>   Tomcat's own /lib folder and thus loaded by Tomcat's "common"
>   classloader.
>
> Your problem sounds much like that you dropped the JDBC driver in your
>   application library folder which is invisible to the "common"
>   classloader. So technically, you have to place the JDBC driver in
>   Tomcat's own /lib folder (or, at least, in a configurable path as
>   specified by common.loader setting in /conf/catalina.properties) in
>   order to make it visible to the data source factory.

Comment: How would I access Tomcat's /lib folder to place the JDBC driver in it?

Comment: how are you deploying your application? are you not deploying it in tomcat?

Comment: Yes we are deploying in tomcat

Comment: ok you need to drop the jdbc driver jar into the tomcat/lib folder and try to run it again.

Comment: yeah I threw in the tomcat jdbc jar in the tomcat/lib and we are still getting the same issue